# as a result of async series, data returns with undefined variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, series

```
async.series([
  function(flow){
  //sth
  if(err){
    flow(err || "Couldn't pass first flow");        
  }else{
    flow();
  }     
}, function(flow){
  //sth
  if(err){
    flow(err || "Couldn't pass second flow");       
  }else{
    flow();
  }
}, function(flow){
  //sth
  if(err){
    flow(err || "Couldn't pass third flow");        
  }else{
    flow();
  }
}, function(flow){
  //sth
  if(err){
    flow(err || "Couldn't pass fourth flow"); 
  }else{
    var arr = [{name: "alex" , age: 21}]
    flow(null, arr)
  }
}
], function(err, arr){//------->Flow complete
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  } else {
  /*I expect to get the arr as; [{name: "alex" , age: 21}] but instead         
   it returns me 4 length array which first 3 elements are undefined as; 
var arr = [undefined, undefined, undefined, {name: "alex" , age: 21}];*/     
}
});
```

What am I missing? 
In the former flows, I just return error if it exists, and data which I want to pass through is in the 4th flow. I pass through it by writing null to the first parameter and data to the second. `flow(null, data)`
Why am I getting when the flow is completed `[undefined, undefined, undefined, {name: "alex" , age: 21}];`?

Comment: your first three calls to `flow` provide no parameter, hence, `undefined` - is `err` a global? because all none of your functions have `err` defined ... what you're missing is any real reason to do what you are doing

Comment: But in the first three calls there is no need to provide any parameter, if err occurs, I just pass the error. The data that I want to pass through is on the 4th call.

Comment: also `flow(err || "Couldn't pass first flow")` is redundant, as err has already been determined to be "truthy", so `flow(err);` has the same effect

Comment: so the first three will result in `undefined` because that's how [async.series](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#series) rolls - read the documentation of [async.series](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#series) - especially what the callback receives: *This function gets a results array (or object) containing **all** the result arguments passed to the task callbacks. Invoked with (err, result)*

Comment: also, if that's your actual code ... `err` is what exactly?

Comment: @jaromanda x i shortened the code for simplicity that's why `err` and calls are not clear. actually, before asking here I looked at the documentation and didn't realize the `all the result arguments` part. Before your warning, I think that it fills the argument if I pass as `flow(null, data)`. Thank you for correcting my misunderstanding